# Pass multiple inputs to a function in a dynamic way in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Thanks for your time for reading and helping.

I have created symbols array as:

```
nvar =3 % no of variables
xk = sym('x',1,nvar)  % this creates three symbols in xk = x1 , x2 , x3
% And an initial value matrix as<br/>
x0 = [2 -2 1]
```

Now i need to declare a function which can be `x1^2 + x1*x2 + x3^2`

So no doubt, i can declare it as

```
f(xk(1),xk(2),xk(3)) = x1^2 + x1*x2 + x3^2
```

But I want to obtain its value at initial point in an iterative / dynamic way
like:

```
f(x0(i),x0(i+1),x0(i+2), . . . . . . x0(n) )
```

I have tried f(xk)

```
f(xk(1:nvar))       % get error like function requires 3 inputs etc etc
```

Comment: Please format your question. It is very hard to understand as it is.

Comment: Please edit your post and define your problem clearly.please take a look at  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi. I understand. There is some problem in formatting. New lines are not showing up even after editing. Can you suggest how can i put it in proper formatting?

Comment: See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting help.

Comment: I am not well aware of html though i have put some changes. I hope it's understandable now. Can you go through it plz?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function with three separate inputs:

```
function out = myfunc1(x1, x2, x3)
    out = x1^2 + x1.*x2 + x3^2;
end
```

or a single input which is an array of 3 values:

```
function out = myfunc2(x)
    out = x(1)^2 + x(1).*x(2) + x(3)^2;
end
```

If you set `x0 = [2, -2, 1]`, then you could call:

```
f = myfunc2(x0)
```

However, it's unclear what you want from "dynamic" calls. You could pass in several sets of 3 inputs by arranging the inputs in rows and changing the function to operate on columns of inputs: e.g.

```
function out = myfunc3(x)
    out = x(1,:)^2 + x(1,:).*x(2,:) + x(3,:)^2;
end
```

Then two rows of inputs: `x0 = [2, -2, 1; -3, 3, 1]` would give two outputs:

```
f = myfunc3(x0)
```

Comment: You are right Justin. <br/>
I am sorry if you found it unclear. <br/>
Actually i was trying to declare a symbolic expression with multiple symbols that could be created by depending upon requirement during runtime.<br/>
But you told me correct way to declare a function. And it can be accessed in a better way (with iteration). So thanks a lot